# How to send Swipe Action to UIView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swipeview, koloda

I am trying to clone Tinder, have done with swipe left (dislike person) and right (like person) by Yalantis/Koloda (https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda). I also have two images for button like/dislike. I wish my mainView will swipe Left/Right when I touch like/dislike image.

```
let likeImageTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.sendSwipeRightAction))
        likeImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        likeImage.addGestureRecognizer(likeImageTap)
```

How should I put in this func?

```
    @objc func sendSwipeRightAction() {
        
    }
```

This is my protocols

```
extension HomeViewController: KolodaViewDataSource, KolodaViewDelegate {
   //...
       func koloda(_ koloda: KolodaView, didSwipeCardAt index: Int, in direction: SwipeResultDirection)
    {
        if direction == .left {
          //...
          print ("swipe left")
        }
        if direction == .right {
          //...
          print("swipe right")
        }
    }
}
```

This is my view

```
@IBOutlet var mainView: KolodaView!
```

I try to use this func, then call it when image tapped, so I can do what I want same as swipe, but the view not change to next image.

```
public func swipe(_ direction: SwipeResultDirection, force: Bool = false)
 { 
//..
}
```

So I want to send swipe action to the view, example:

```
mainView.sendActions(for: .swipeLeft)
```

How should I do? Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: did you create swipe function?

Comment: No, I want to send action swipe to UIView, like I swipe by my hand. How should I create swipe function to do that?

Comment: from what i read in the lib, you only need call mainView.swipe(.left)

Comment: OMG, I have just see it. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is code in [example](https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda/blob/master/Example/Koloda/ViewController.swift)

```
kolodaView.swipe(.left)
kolodaView.swipe(.right)
```

your code will be like this

```
@objc func sendSwipeRightAction() {
        mainView.swipe(.right)
    }
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks, I have just cloned Example and see it.